# Google Maps API v3 AJAX LOAD with Library Places

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project that require to load a google map (I am using the api version 3), in a modal popup window.

The content of the modal is loaded using ajax call, and what I want to obtain is to load the google map api in a dynamic way.

The following code let me obtain the exact result that I was looking for, but apparently it also have a side effect that I am not able to figure out how solve (maybe I am doing something wrong in the whole process, and I just not able to figure out what).
Every help will be really appreciate, and I thank in advance who will be able to clarify my mind.

NOTE(1): I used 2 different version of the code (one loading the api using the url parameter, the other using the google load functionality), the result it's the same.

NOTE(2): The full development is made using Ruby on Rails 3, and trying to take full advantage of the asset pipeline functionality.

**CODE (EXPLANATION)**

(1) JQUERY FUNCTION - used to load external scripts in a dynamic way

```
jQuery.externalScript = function(url, options) {
  // allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
  options = $.extend(options || {}, {
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    url: url
  });
  // Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
  // Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
  return jQuery.ajax(options);
};
```

(2) JS FUNCTION - This make the dynamic call to the google load api

```
function google_load_api_call() {
  var gmap_src = 'https://www.google.com/jsapi';
  $.externalScript(gmap_src).done(function() {
        load_google_maps_api_via_google_ajax_api_loader();
  });;
}
```

(3) JS FUNCTION - This make the dynamic call to the google maps api using google load

```
function load_google_maps_api_via_google_ajax_api_loader() {
  google.load("maps", "3", {other_params:'libraries=places&sensor=false', callback: function(){
    initialize(); // initialize your map in here
  }});
}
```

(3) JS FUNCTION - This initialize the google map (used as callback)

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 0,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
```

(4) RAILS JS.ERB - This is used to load up the modal, and load all the contents(e.g. the map)

```
$('#section').append('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial=>'locations/new_page/locations_new')) %>');

$(function() {
   modal_create_new_location(); // This call the modal to show
   google_load_api_call(); // This load the google load api and the map
   create_new_location_data_submit(); // This submit in ajax the form data
});
```

**CODE (RESULTS AND ISSUES)**

The code perform its task perfectly, the modal load, the map load, the library place load and works. Everything seems completely right (in chrome, or safari, no issue).

What create my huge torment and pain is an issue (actually a warning) raised by firefox, only if I include in the google map api call also a library (like places or geormetry for example) - SEE The JS Function NUMBER (3), the line in which there is [other_params:'libraries=places]. If I don't load the library also firefox will not complain anymore, and everything works perfectly.

The WARNING raised by Firefox is the following:

**Error: Support for eval(code, scopeObject) has been removed. Use |with (scopeObject) eval(code);| instead.**

and it's referred to the:

https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_US/mapfiles/api-3/10/19/{main,places}.js

at the line 9

Can someone please let me understand what I am doing wrong here?
I should not call the library using a dynamic call?
How then I can use the autocomplete map functionality?

Comment: Nobody can help with this?